# Concatinating String XSL

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have these values in my xml

`<xsl:variable name="template" select="mail/template"/>` (coming as template4)
`<xsl:variable name="portalname" select="mail/portalname"/>` (coming as testingportal)

and I need to have something like this created as finally

```
<LINK rel="stylesheet" href="/rezsystem/rezsystem_hansa/jboss-4.0.3SP1/server/default/deploy/RezgEmailService.war/xsl/testingportal/css/template4/rezbase_mail.css" type="text/css"/>
```

and in like java

```
String str =  "/rezsystem/rezsystem_hansa/jboss-4.0.3SP1/server/default/deploy/RezgEmailService.war/xsl/"+ portalname+"/css/"+template+"/rezbase_mail.css";
```

how to do concatenation on this scenario.??

Answer (score -2, accepted):

See: http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat('/rezsystem/rezsystem_hansa/jboss-4.0.3SP1/server/default/deploy/RezgEmailService.war/xsl/', $portalname, '/css/', $template, '/rezbase_mail.css')" />
```

Or use `string-join`:

```
<xsl:value-of select="string-join(('/rezsystem/rezsystem_hansa/jboss-4.0.3SP1/server/default/deploy/RezgEmailService.war/xsl/', $portalname, '/css/', $template '/rezbase_mail.css'))" />
```

Comment: In the first solution, the multiple calls on concat() seem unnecessary. concat() takes a variable number of arguments. In the second solution, there's a missing set of parentheses: string-join() takes a single argument, typically a sequence. Also note, concat() does not require XSLT 2.0; and Erlock's solution using AVTs is simpler. Therefore downvoting.

Answer (score 3):

You must use [attribute value templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates):

```
<LINK rel="stylesheet" href="/rezsystem/rezsystem_hansa/jboss-4.0.3SP1/server/defaultdeploy/RezgEmailService.war/xsl/{$portalname}/css/{$template}/rezbase_mail.css" type="text/css"/>
```